# Whitney stratification of a $\mathbb C^*$-invariant hypersuface in $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $H\subset \mathbb C^n$ be an irreducible hypersurface invariant under a diagonal $\mathbb C^*$-action with positive weights ($H$ is given by a quasi-homogeneous polynomial). Consider the Whitney stratification of $H$.

**Question.** Is it true that $0\subset \mathbb C^n$ is not a stratum of this stratification if an only if $H$ is a smooth hypersurface? If no, how to describe all such irreducible $\mathbb C^*$-invariant $H$ for which $0$ is not a stratum?

Comment: The answer to the first question is "no" as you can take $H$ to be the hypersurface defined by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$, which looks like $0$ is a Whitney stratum, but isn't, because it's secretly a hypersurface in the variables $x,y,z,w$. It might be reasonable to guess that all examples arise from this trick, but I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: Thanks Will! So one has to exclude some kind of products by a linear space...